# MQTT with JAVA- When publish some data with QoS1 I lose some data

Tags: java, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I am working on my MQTT project and I am a beginner at this. I want to publish some data with all QoS levels and subscribe to them and doing time measurements. I am using a Raspberry pi as a Subscriber and also I am using Mosquitto broker in same Raspberry pi. I am publishing data with my own laptop. I was expecting that when I publish and subscribe data with Qos 0, I would lose some data but my subscriber received all the data. By the way, I published 10million random values with 8 parallel thread without any `thread.sleep()`. These are part of my publisher codes:

```
final String temperature = tempratureNumber + "°C"; //temperatureNumber is random value.
byte[] payload = temperature.getBytes();  
tempratureBadroomTopic.publish(payload,1,true);

//And these are my connect options:
MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
options.setCleanSession(false);
options.setWill(client.getTopic("home/LWT"), "I'm gone :(".getBytes(), 1, false);
options.setMaxInflight(32768); // for too many publishes error.
client.connect(options);
```

Also these are part of my Subscriber codes:

```
final String topic1 = "home/brightness1/bathroom";
mqttClient.subscribe(topic1,1);
```

Also, I was expecting that, when I publish 200k random values with QoS1, it will take more time but I will receive at least 200k random values may be more than 200k because of QoS level. However, sometimes I received less than 200k values e.g 199780. I can't understand why I am losing data.
What could be the reason for these situations I encountered?
Have a good day.

Comment: I've seen something similar caused by the Mosquitto setting `max_queued_messages`; this defaults to 100 and after that messages are silently dropped.

Comment: Are you also subscribing at QOS1?

Comment: @Brits thank you! I am currently trying this. I did 5 tests and all of them received 7 more messages at qos 1, by the way I published 200k messages . I will keep doing tests but something is confusing me. Why subcriber always received 7 more messages?

Comment: @hardillb yes I do. I guess so :) there are codes above about it

Comment: @HarunÖzdemir sorry you have not provided enough information to enable a response (e.g. what did you set `max_queued_messages` to). There are a number of components involved (publisher, broker, subscriber) and the issue could be in any of them (including within your code). The best way to get an answer is to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (but you might want to enable logging on the broker and check for any errors it reports first).

Comment: @Brits thanks for your reply. I set `max_queued_messages` to 10000. And the codes I shared, almost all the ones related to mqtt in all my code. The rest of the my codes related to threads and paralel procecess etc. I can understand that these informations might not enough to identify the problem but may be someone encountured like this problem before.

Comment: @HarunÖzdemir Set `max_queued_messages` to 0 if you want to eliminate this as a possible cause. If you are sending 200k messages the queue may get over 10000 depending upon other settings (e.g.. `max_inflight_messages`) and your subscriber. Unfortunately without full information (e.g. broker configuration) I cannot know if this is an issue I have seen before (can only guess).

Comment: Also please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64654382/edit) the question rather than try and add technical details as comments.